Clarification needed on the multiplication of elements of a tensor algebra
I'm reading Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra: Part 1 and which gives the definition of a tensor algebra as:

If $M$ is a $k$-module, define
$$
T(M)=\bigoplus_{p \geq 0}\left(\bigotimes^p M\right)=k \oplus M \oplus\left(M \otimes_k M\right) \oplus\left(M \otimes_k M \otimes_k M\right) \oplus \cdots .
$$
Define a scalar multiplication on $T(M)$ by
$$
r\left(y_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_p\right)=\left(r y_1\right) \otimes y_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_p
$$
if $r \in k$ and $y_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_p \in \bigotimes^p M$, and multiplication $\mu: \bigotimes^p M \times \bigotimes^q M \rightarrow \bigotimes^{p+q} M$, for $p, q \geq 1$ by
$$
\mu:\left(x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_p, y_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_q\right) \mapsto x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_p \otimes y_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_q .
$$

later in a proof he adds:

Now define the product of two homogeneous elements by the formula in the definition. It follows that multiplication $\mu: T(M) \times T(M) \rightarrow T(M)$ is
$$
\mu:\left(\sum_p m_p, \sum_q m_q^{\prime}\right) \mapsto \sum_{p, q} m_p \otimes m_q^{\prime},
$$
where $m_p \in \bigotimes^p M$ and $m_q^{\prime} \in \bigotimes^q M$.

After reading this and Construction of tensor algebra: extending the multiplication from being defined on pure tensors I wanted to check that I'm understanding  exactly what the elements of the tensor algebra are and how they multiply.
I'm assuming that in the proof section $\sum_p m_p$ is a general element of T(M) (as it is a sum between 'gradings'). If this is the case then I assume that $m_p$ is an arbitrary element of $\bigotimes^p M$ which would mean $m_p=\sum_n a_n$ for pure tensors $a_n$. It then says to define the product between these homogeneous elements. Is this done the same way as in the proof statement ie $\mu:\left(\sum_n a_n, \sum_t a_t^{\prime}\right) \mapsto \sum_{n, t} a_n \otimes a_t^{\prime}$ (which is equal to $\sum_n a_n \otimes \sum_t a_t^{\prime}$ ?). I can’t really see any other way of defining multiplication between homogeneous elements. Would this then make the multiplication of 2 general elements of T(M) $ \sum_{p, q} m_p \otimes m_q^{\prime}=\sum_{p, q} (\sum_n a_{n, p} \otimes \sum_t a_{t, q})=\sum_{p, q}(\sum_{n, t} a_{n, p} \otimes a_{t, q}^{\prime})$ (where $a_{n,p}$ are pure tensors make up the sum in the homogeneous elements of each $\bigotimes^p M$).
Any help clarifying this for me would be appreciated.

Yes, the key thing to observe is that the first $\mu$ is bilinear.
